Append values into file 1 using key-value pairs from file 2, bash
I have seen many versions of questions like this but not a good one using bash (unless I have missed it please direct me to one).
I want to extract the keys and values from keyvalue.txt based on the keys I obtain from file1.txt.
The format of the files are as follows:
file1.txt which contains the 'taxid' KEY in column 10 (before the species name).
1e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|296972128|gb|HM278533.1|,249,1309,100,237,98.394,1.37e-118,438,0,Uncultured,bacterium clone ncd557a11c1 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|2259146620|emb|OW925276.1|,249,363,100,237,98.394,1.37e-118,438,0,uncultured,Anaerolineae bacterium DNA containing 16S-23S intergenic spacer region, clone 43
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|1771871051|emb|LR646018.1|,249,1412,100,228,97.189,1.38e-113,422,253,uncultured,bacterium partial 16S rRNA gene
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|1271843868|gb|MG277305.1|,249,363,100,225,96.787,6.40e-112,416,253,Uncultured,bacterium clone OTU_3084 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|1271845089|gb|MG278526.1|,249,363,98,192,93.004,1.42e-93,355,253,Uncultured,bacterium clone OTU_4378 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|378812876|gb|JQ408060.1|,249,1299,100,192,92.369,1.42e-93,355,43,Uncultured,bacterium clone SEV1BE061 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|151655702|gb|EU012237.1|,249,1030,100,189,91.968,6.59e-92,350,43,Uncultured,Chloroflexi bacterium clone 251 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|440507165|gb|KC001159.1|,249,1308,100,189,92.000,6.59e-92,350,0,Unidentified,marine bacterioplankton clone P3-1B_21 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|2259561892|emb|OW932746.1|,249,363,100,186,91.566,3.07e-90,344,391,uncultured,Anaerolineae bacterium DNA containing 16S-23S intergenic spacer region, clone 43
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|165972207|dbj|AB257651.1|,249,1468,100,186,91.700,3.07e-90,344,391,Uncultured,Chloroflexus sp. gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone: Dolo_29

keyvalue.txt:
0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
21,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Caulobacterales,Caulobacteraceae,Phenylobacterium,Phenylobacterium immobile
33,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Myxococcaceae,Myxococcus,Myxococcus fulvus
35,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Myxococcaceae,Corallococcus,Corallococcus macrosporus
41,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Stigmatella,Stigmatella aurantiaca
43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
254,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indoltheticum
391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.
396,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium phaseoli

I have been trying to grab the keys from file1.txt but for some reason I am getting additional values being saved and so I am unable to properly then extract the values from keyvalue.txt.
Here's what I've been trying but it isn't working well:
for line in $(cat file1.txt); do key=$( echo $line | cut -d"," -f10); \
if grep $key keyvalue.txt; then grep $key keyvalue.txt; fi; done

But I am getting a lot of weird output where it is grepping the wrong keys and essentially just returns my entire keyvalue.txt with just a lot of weird spaces and it's a whole mess. I think because the species names (everything after column 10) with it's extra commas and such are causing such issues, that even just echoing the lines is causing some weird stuff to happen.
For example (just testing it on one other random line in the file):
 for line in $(cat file1.txt); do echo $line; done

Output:
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|165972207|dbj|AB257651.1|,249,1468,100,186,91.700,3.07e-90,344,391,Uncultured,Chloroflexus
sp.
gene
for
16S
rRNA,
partial
sequence,
clone:
Dolo_29

When it should just be:
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|165972207|dbj|AB257651.1|,249,1468,100,186,91.700,3.07e-90,344,391,Uncultured,Chloroflexus sp. gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone: Dolo_29

Expected output:
0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli  
391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.
391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.


you state you want the 10th comma-delimited column but the sample data you've provided only has 8 comma-delimited columns ... ??

oops sorry I somehow pasted the wrong info I will fix that quickly!!

please update the question with sample data from both files (file1.txt and keyvalue.txt), making sure to provide a mix of lines that match and do not match; then update the question with the (wrong) results generated by your code and the (correct) expected results, making sure both sets of output correspond with the sample inputs you provide

for line in $(cat file1.txt) is going to break a line into separate chunks based on white space, eg, if a  line looks like a,b c,d e,f,g then you'll end up with 3 passes through the loop with line being set to the values of a,b, c,d and e,f,g; what you probably want is something like while read -r line; do ... done < file1.txt

Yup. That fixed it! I've added my solution to the top. Thanks so much for your quick help.

what's supposed to happen if there is no match between the two files? or are you guaranteed to have a match for every line/key?

It should be a guarantee match. The keyvalue.txt file was created using the file1.txt taxids which I extracted beforehand and kept only unique ids, then I obtained all the lineage info for it. Originally I could have just kept all taxids without keeping the unique ids, and then just directly align the output but there were so many more sequences this time it was causing a lot of issues extracting information of NCBI using Entrez utilities.

@markp-fuso  grep -f <(cut -d, -f 10 <file1.txt) keyvalue.txt

your expected output doesn't make sense, eg, how do you go from a single input line with key = 253 to 3x identical output lines with key = 253? it doesn't appear that you're actually appending anything to the input line; actually, it looks like the only line with appended data is the first line where key = 0

you state appending the full line ... from keyvalue.txt to the end of the lines but your expected output (and output from your answer) show the contents of keyvalue.txt being at the beginning of the lines (as opposed to being appended to the ends of the output lines); have you mixed up the names of the sample input files?

Updated my question - I removed the whole append part because I realized as writing it out it would just be easier and cleaner to get separate output that I can append later myself after. The output is just a separate output entirely.

It's a lot more efficient to use a tool like join here -- requires both your inputs to be sorted on the join key, but that's a lot faster than the kind of logic you're running here where you fork multiple subprocesses for every single input line.

Through multiple updates we're given conflicting information about what the expected output should look like:

textual description (from original question) says to append lines from keyvalue.txt to the end of lines from file1.txt
expected output (from original question) shows one line from file1.txt being appended to the end of a line from keyvalue.txt, but then nothing appended to the rest of the lines (from keyvalue.txt)
OP's answer shows lines from file1.txt being replaced by the 'matching' lines from keyvalue.txt

If OP's answer is showing the actual expected results then one alternative that eliminates a) the dual subshells spawned for $(echo ... | cut ...) and b) the dual grep calls:
while read -r line
do  
    IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "${line}"     # split $line on comma delimiter, place results in array arr[]
    grep "^${arr[9]}," keyvalue.txt      # bash array numbering starts with 0 so arr[9] == 10th column
done < file1.txt

A more efficient approach that doesn't require rescanning keyvalue.txt for each pass through the while loop:
awk -F',' '
NR==FNR     { keys[$1]=$0; next }     # 1st file (keyvalue.txt): use 1st field as index in keys[] array to save entire line; skip to next line of input
$10 in keys { print keys[$10]   }     # 2nd file (file1.txt): if 10th field is an index in keys[] array then print line from keys[] array
' keyvalue.txt file1.txt

NOTE: this requires awk to store the entire contents of keyvalue.txt in memory; would only be a problem if keyvalue.txt is so large that awk (and the underlying OS/host) runs out of memory
These both generate:
0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.
391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.


On the other hand, if we go by just the textual description (from the original question) then it sounds like what the OP wants:

both files (file1.txt and keyvalue.txt) are comma-delimited
we want to match column #1 from keyvalue.txt with column #10 from file1.txt
if we find a match then we're to append the line from keyvalue.txt to the end of the line from file1.txt (using a comma to separate the two data sets)

While this is doable in bash we'll tweak the more efficient awk solution:
awk '
BEGIN       { FS = OFS = ","      }     # define intput/output field separators
NR==FNR     { keys[$1]=$0; next   }
$10 in keys { print $0, keys[$10] }     # print current line (2nd file) plus line from 1st file
' keyvalue.txt file1.txt

This generates:
1e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|296972128|gb|HM278533.1|,249,1309,100,237,98.394,1.37e-118,438,0,Uncultured,bacterium clone ncd557a11c1 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence,0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|2259146620|emb|OW925276.1|,249,363,100,237,98.394,1.37e-118,438,0,uncultured,Anaerolineae bacterium DNA containing 16S-23S intergenic spacer region, clone 43,0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|1771871051|emb|LR646018.1|,249,1412,100,228,97.189,1.38e-113,422,253,uncultured,bacterium partial 16S rRNA gene,253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|1271843868|gb|MG277305.1|,249,363,100,225,96.787,6.40e-112,416,253,Uncultured,bacterium clone OTU_3084 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence,253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|1271845089|gb|MG278526.1|,249,363,98,192,93.004,1.42e-93,355,253,Uncultured,bacterium clone OTU_4378 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence,253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|378812876|gb|JQ408060.1|,249,1299,100,192,92.369,1.42e-93,355,43,Uncultured,bacterium clone SEV1BE061 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence,43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|151655702|gb|EU012237.1|,249,1030,100,189,91.968,6.59e-92,350,43,Uncultured,Chloroflexi bacterium clone 251 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence,43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|440507165|gb|KC001159.1|,249,1308,100,189,92.000,6.59e-92,350,0,Unidentified,marine bacterioplankton clone P3-1B_21 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence,0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|2259561892|emb|OW932746.1|,249,363,100,186,91.566,3.07e-90,344,391,uncultured,Anaerolineae bacterium DNA containing 16S-23S intergenic spacer region, clone 43,391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,gi|165972207|dbj|AB257651.1|,249,1468,100,186,91.700,3.07e-90,344,391,Uncultured,Chloroflexus sp. gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone: Dolo_29,391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.


With the help of @markp-fuso, this is a solution that worked for me:
while read -r line; do key=$( echo $line | cut -d"," -f10); if grep -wq "^${key}" keyvalue.txt; then grep "^${key}" keyvalue.txt; fi; done < file1.txt

Output:

    0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
    0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
    253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
    253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
    253,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Flavobacteriia,Flavobacteriales,Weeksellaceae,Chryseobacterium,Chryseobacterium indologenes
    43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
    43,Bacteria,Myxococcota,Myxococcia,Myxococcales,Archangiaceae,Cystobacter,Cystobacter fuscus
    0,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Enterobacterales,Enterobacteriaceae,Escherichia,Escherichia coli
    391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.
    391,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Alphaproteobacteria,Hyphomicrobiales,Rhizobiaceae,Rhizobium,Rhizobium sp.

I hope this can be helpful to others with similar questions.

Or shorter: while read -r key ;do grep -wq "^${key}" keyvalues.txt && grep "^${key}" keyvalues.txt; done < <(cut -d"," -f10 <file1.txt) Not only shorter, this will be quicker as cut is run only once and reduce forks!

this doesn't appear to actually append anything to the end of your input data; the duplicated lines indicate a one-to-many match but ... shouldn't the lines be unique due to the appendage of data from the other file? this output also doesn't match the expected output you've provided in the question

I don't understand why if grep -q ; then grep..!!

grep -wq matches whole words, quietly. So grep -wq "$k" && grep "$k" makes sure you only get lines where the whole key matches, and not, for example "10" matching a line that starts with "100".

I use grep -wq "^${key}" which should properly grep the whole key at the start of the line. I use the if then because there might be some errors where some keys didn't properly get added into the keyvalue.txt file so I want to isolate those. I am still adding some extra controls into that if statement such as, if the grep did not work then print out "ERROR" or something like that.

Anything where you run $(...) or an external command like grep or cut in an inner loop is quite slow in bash -- I'd only take this kind of approach if you know with certainty your input files will be very short; if you have megabytes or gigabytes of data, this won't hold up. (Whereas something like the <(cut ...) approach suggested by F. Hauri above only runs cut once, not once per time through the loop).

This code is extremely buggy and inefficient, don't do this. Look again at the 1st awk script in @markp-fuso's answer as it does exactly what you're apparently trying to do in this answer but does it robustly, efficiently, concisely, and portably.
